# how to monitor cpu frequency in android system

Tags: android, linux

Recently,I am making a system program(application) to monitor cpu frequency info.I found that we can use cpuinfo to dump each cpu in mobile.But I don't want to use shell command to get these infos in my application.So I want to know how the cpuinfo command to get cpu infos,is there system call?

Answer (score 2):

Just open and read from `/proc/cpuinfo` in your application.

Comment: Is there any better method?Such as function call,is there any such method supplied by linux?

Comment: Cpuinfo dumps a lot of infos that only a little information related to my requirement,so I have to parse these infos.So I hope the linux exists some function calls can finish my purpose